# mailchimp: Directly subscribe users on clicking submit button

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp for subscribing all the users to newsletter and I have added the following Newsletter subscription form (mailchimp's embedded form)

```
   <div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="http://mysite.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=77819ee26cc4d495467172e15&amp;id=e2798374aa" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-   form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" value="Sign       up for newsletter..." required>
<div class="clear"></div><input type="submit" value="" name="subscribe" id="mc- embedded-subscribe" class="button">
   </form>
 </div>
```

It is working fine but when user clicks on submit button, it gets redirected to other page where the user have to fill profile information i.e name,address. etc. After filling the information, the user gets subscribed. Now the problem is that I want users should get directly subscribed after clicking on submit button. Can anybody guide me in this???

Comment: They still have to opt-in. However, you can change the redirect url and welcome email, etc. from within the mailchimp dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code, this is newslatter from Aweber...

```
<div class="aweber">
<form class="forms" action="CHANGE FORM ACTION HERE" method="post"><input     type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1455415225" /><input type="hidden"    name="meta_split_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="unit" value="aweberblog" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="YOUR THANKU PAGE URL HERE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="sb-index" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="from" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_forward_vars" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_redirect_onlist" value="IF USER ALREADY SUBSCRIBD HERE ENTER URL FOR THAT"/>
    <label for="email"></label>
    <input id="email"  placeholder="Enter Your Email" style="width:45%; border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px; height: 35px; float:left;padding-left: 10px;" type="text" name="from" value=""/>
    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/submitt.png">
    </form>
</div>
```